# reorder url parameters (GET) with nginx or apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, rewrite

Is that possible to reorder the GET parameters from a request (alphabetical) before it hits my application ?

Comment: You should not want this. Probably you should fix your application.

Comment: It is not in production yet, and we are still exploring possibilities. The point was to generate cache keys based on url

Comment: My impression is that you're trying to solve the wrong problem, it should be handled by your application

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Absolutely possible with mod_rewrite.
Suppose your Query parameters are /a=1&b=2

Your rewrite rule will look like below

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=(.*)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^b=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/$1?b=%2&a=%1 [P,L]
```

Where localhost:8080 is your backend application server, I haven't tried this, but should work.